# How to make Material UI v1.0 Dialog background transparent?

Tags: css, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I am trying to make put a CircularProgress inside a dialog box. But the dialog box background is white and cannot be set to transparent as in earlier version - Material UI v0.2

```
style={{
    width: '200px',
    marginLeft: '40%',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}}
```

**I need to make the dialog background transparent.** Here is my code:

```
<Dialog
      bodyStyle={{margin: 0, padding: 0}}
      open={true}
      style={{
        width: '200px',
        marginLeft: '40%',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      }}
      overlayStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
    >
      <CircularProgress
        style={{display: 'inline-block'}}
        size={50}
        color={"#00db49"}
      />
</Dialog>
```

**And how to remove the scrollbar in the dialog as shown in the image?**
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can override the Paper element css properties using *PaperProps* property in Dialog component. (from here : https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/)

as an example :

```
    <Dialog
      onClose={this.handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
      {...other}
      BackdropProps={{
        classes: {
         root: classes.root
        }
       }
      }
      PaperProps ={{
        classes: {
         root: classes.paper
        }
      }}
      >
      <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Set backup 
 account
      </DialogTitle>
       // code you want is here   
    </Dialog>
```

and paper style should be provided as this:

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },

  paper: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    boxShadow: "none",
    overflow: "hidden"
  },
};
```

hope this will help you and here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/j3wmyv7w2w

Comment: How to make the root background have a transparent overlay?

Answer (score 6):

*Ah.. overriding material ui css is always a challenge*

As you cannot directly override material-ui nested div css using style and classes.
Because dialog also inherits **MODAL** properties for that background overlay that's why you have to use one of the props listed in Modal props and for this use-case you have to override **Backdrop** props listed in Modal api docs.

In simple terms just write this into your dialog

```
// outside react class 
const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  }
};

// In your react class 
<Dialog
  onClose={this.handleClose}
  aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
  {...other}
  BackdropProps={{
  classes: {
    root: classes.root
    }
   }}
  >
```

I have attached working example of material ui in codesandbox. please refer below

Make sure to wrap your component using withStyles() as in example below

CodeSandBox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/5xp76wn3xp

And to hide scrollbar this is already answered here: [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Let me know if you require more help

Comment: I meant the scrollbar in the dialog besides the progress. Could you please check on it. (this can be seen in the screenshot)

Comment: The codesandbox example dialog background is not transparent?

Comment: Hi @ShanikaEdiriweera I was not able to replicate this scenario on code sandbox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/535w4r82jn
If you can provide link working link to the problem that would be great 
In the meantime, you use some CSS to remove scrollbar on a dialog 

try some { min-height, overflow: hidden,  } on dialog root class of dialog

Comment: yes its transparent in this link 
https://codesandbox.io/s/5xp76wn3xp
do you not able to see changes ?

Comment: I think you haven't understood the problem correctly. What I wanted to make transparent was not the background screen but the background of the dialog box itself. See the accepted answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way

```
<Dialog sx={{ '& .MuiBackdrop-root': { backgroundColor: 'transparent' } }} >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Modal component to do that, and so, in Modal props you're going to use the prop: hideBackdrop

Just like this:

```
<Modal open={true} hideBackdrop >
  <your code here />
</Modal>
```

Here's the documentation about Modal and the "hideBackDrop" prop:
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/